# Error using RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton

Tags: r, rcpp, packaging

I want to create a package containing a RcppArmadillo function:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)

sourceCpp("calculSignSim.cpp")

RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(name = "calculSignSimCPP",list = "calculSignSim")
```

The function created by `sourceCpp` works fine. 
However, this latter line gives me the following error:

```
Calling package.skeleton to create basic package.
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './calculSignSimCPP/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding RcppArmadillo settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
 >> added useDynLib and importFrom directives to NAMESPACE
 >> added Makevars file with Rcpp settings
 >> added Makevars.win file with RcppArmadillo settings
 >> added example src file using armadillo classes
 >> added example Rd file for using armadillo classes
Error in Rcpp::compileAttributes(root) : 
  Evaluation error: D:/R packages/calculSignSimCPP/R/calculSignSim.R:3:21: unexpected '<'
2: function (lemmesV, ulemmesV, optionLien) 
3: .Primitive(".Call")(<
                       ^.
In addition: Warning message:
In dump(item, file = file.path(code_dir, sprintf("%s.R", list0[item])),  :
  deparse may be incomplete
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

When I do not explicitely indicate which function I want to include, i.e. when I do

```
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(name = "calculSignSimCPP")
```

Everything works fine, but the created package does not contain my function...

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe you should read the [R packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/).

Comment: Might be a bug in `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`, please feel free to investigate and fix.  I primarily use it _without a supplied function_ and that just works.

Comment: @F.Privé: I prefer [primary sources such as the Rcpp book](https://www.amazon.com/Seamless-Integration-Rcpp-Dirk-Eddelbuettel/dp/1461468671/ref=as_sl_pc_qf_sp_asin_til?tag=rcpp-20&linkCode=w00&linkId=3T5SIL7YILBM32PB&creativeASIN=1461468671).

Comment: And iof course you can _just copy your function info `src/` and have a working package_.

Comment: Wow ok, it was this simple. Thanks a lot, Dirk!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You're biased as the author :'). Besides, *R Packages* is free.